# How to type-check constant dictionaries that are being dynamically accessed?

Tags: python, mypy

I have a const.py file which holds a few constant values for my application. Some of these constants are dictionaries. To access the values of these dictionaries, keys are often calculated at runtime (see example below).

I'm using mypy for my project and would like to know how to properly type-check these dictionaries.

Example:

In `const.py`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

PATHS = {
    'darwin': {
        'path_x': Path('...'),
        'path_y': Path('...')
    },
    'windows': {
        'path_x': Path('...'),
        'path_y': Path('...')
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my app:

```py
system = platform.system()
path_x = PATHS[system.lower()]['path_x']
```

When I now do something with `path_x`, say, pass it to a function that requires a path-like object, mypy will rightly complain about `incompatible type "object"`.

What is the preferred way of typing the PATHS dictionary? Should I make every constant dict a `TypedDict` (might get pretty verbose if for every constant there will be an extra few lines of TypedDict definitions)? And/or maybe it makes sense to use `Final` from the mypy_extensions?